# How can i compare int to a String Array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

Im trying to compare the user input which is int to a String array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array{

    public static void main(String[]args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number;

    String [] month = new String[13];
    month[0] = "Null";
    month[1] = "January";
    month[2] = "February";
    month[3] = "March";
    month[4] = "April";
    month[5] = "May";
    month[6] = "June";
    month[7] = "July";
    month[8] = "August";
    month[9] = "September";
    month[10] = "October";
    month[11] = "November";
    month[12] = "December";

    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    number = input.nextInt();

    }
}
```

Comment: You can convert your int to string before you comapre : Integer.toString(YOUR_INT_VAR)

Comment: You need to specify what you are asking for. It does not make sense to do `Integer.CompareTo(String[])`

Comment: 'Compare' are you sure it's the good word ? Or from int input get the String month ?

Answer (score 3):

Just use input as the index, say they input 1 for January, then you can just call the index:

```
System.out.println("You've selected the month of: " + month[number]);
```

Will output "January" for `month[number]`, you will also have to check for out of range, of course.

Comment: *Probably* what OP asked for. But it's hard to tell without having a proper question in the first place. Either way, have my up-vote.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this solution :D

Comment: Please accept and possibly upvote if this answered your question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
System.out.println("Please enter a number between 0 and 13");
        Integer userNmber = input.nextInt();

        if(userNmber > month.length-1){
            System.out.println("Please enter a number between 0 and 13");
            userNmber = input.nextInt();
        }

        if(month[userNmber] != null)
            System.out.println("Input from user " + userNmber + " match with month : "+ month[userNmber]);
```

Answer:
Please enter a number between 0 and 13

13

Please enter a number between 0 and 13

12

Input from user 12 match with month : December

Comment: Do you know how I can check if the output is out of range ?

Comment: you can use like this if(userNmber > month.length-1) then force the user to enter the value between 0 and 13...

Comment: It works but I tried with a negative number and gives this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at Array.main(Array.java:34)

Comment: you will need to add condition if userNumber is less than zero then force the user to input positive integer between the value the program can hanlde

Comment: thank you so much for the help :D